# Capture ViewGroup into an Image File

Tags: java, android, android-layout, screen-capture

I have a simple combination of one `ImageView` and two `TextViews` over it. I would like to make the `TextViews` overlap the `ImageView`, and then save the combination as a whole (as PNG for example).

I know I can layer the `TextViews` over the `ImageView` using a `FrameLayout`, which I am already doing. Now what I am wondering is, how can I export that to an image?

I read various posts about using a Canvas. Is there a way to just export the `FrameLayout` as a PNG image, say, or do I need to create a canvas, add the `ImageView` and `TextViews`, and export the canvas itself as a PNG?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Can it be done easily?**, YES

**How?**

Well, I happen to have made a function for this the other day and it's really straightforward (make sure you have the write to external device permission). All you do is specify which view (it will include all the children views too) you want to "paint" to a `Bitmap` and afterwards you can either save it as a file like you say, or use it somewhere in you app.

```
public void captureView(int viewId,String filename){
    //Find the view we are after
    View    view = (View) findViewById(viewId);
    //Create a Bitmap with the same dimensions 
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), 
                                       view.getHeight(), 
                                       Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    //Draw the view inside the Bitmap
    view.draw(new Canvas(image)); 

    //Store to sdcard
    try {
       String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
       File myFile = new File(path,filename);
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

       image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out); //Output
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Notes** Avoid trying to execute this code on the `onCreate` method since you're likely to be trying to fetch the width and height of the view prior to it being drawn and therefor will result in an error since the dimensions of the Bitmap can **not** be 0.

**Does it capture the view as it is or as it was created?**

I wasn't really sure at first but after a little testing, it appears that what you see is what you get, so if you have something rotating or different from the original disposition on launch it will reflect this in the capture. This may or may not be what you're after but it's what it provides. Here's an example of a `LinearLayout` captured (no screenshot or crop, just direct from the device).

[image: view capture]

Comment: Thank you, this looks amazing ! Should I call it on the individual TextViews/ImageView, or call it on the Layout itself?

Comment: Layouts all extend ViewGroup which at the same time extends View. So you can pass anything that extends a view I would assume. Works with `LinearLayouts` you can capture the whole screen or a fraction.

Hope it helps, +1 and accept if its useful ;)

Comment: Yes, surely. Give me just 10-15 minutes to test and I will come back here right after

Comment: Works with full layout, that's (in my example) LinearLayout with relatives inside, and all sorts of widgets

Comment: 100 points for this one, worked like a charm, didnt even need to change anything much